# SSL Configuration for WCF REST Service with Custom Bindings

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, ssl, custom-binding

I have a WCF REST service that has to accept a raw input stream from a client. In order to receive the raw stream, I'm using a custom binding in my web.config file. The service works fine if I set it to connect over standard HTTP. However, I'm having difficulty getting it to work over HTTPS.

***Manual addressing is not supported with message level security. Configure the binding ('CustomBinding', 'http://tempuri.org/') to use transport security or to not do manual addressing.***

Below is the configuration I'm using for HTTP:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="LocalBehavior" name="RestService.CreditService">
     <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" contract="RestService.ICreditService" />
</service>

<behavior name="LocalBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

<binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
    <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="RestService.Data.RawContentTypeMapper, RestService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000"
           transferMode="Streamed" />
</binding>
```

And here is the configuration I'm using for HTTPS:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior" name="RestService.CreditService">
        <endpoint address="basic" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" name="httpsEndpoint" contract="RestService.ICreditService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://sitcreditserviceszalecorp.cloudapp.net:3389/CreditService.svc" />
            <add baseAddress="https://sitcreditserviceszalecorp.cloudapp.net:443/CreditService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
</service>

<behavior name="SecureBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>

<binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
          <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="RestService.Data.RawContentTypeMapper, RestService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"
                  requireSecurityContextCancellation ="true">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" requireClientCertificate="false" />
</binding>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue until I came across an article suggesting to remove the security element. That worked for me.